# Shell how configure command to always work with some params?

Tags: shell, command, parameters

I want to know how to configure your environment to execute some command with specific params everytime you use it.
So, if I have a command named:

> spec

I want to know where I configure my bash to always use:

> spec -c --format nested

instead of just 'spec'

I tried to put this like an alias on my .bashrc file, like:

> alias spec='spec -c --format pretty'

but didn't work.
Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to execute your `.bashrc` after editing it?

`. ~/.bashrc` will do it.

Also, your two commands don't match.  You have "nested" in one and "pretty" in the other.

Comment: Thanks man, you're the guy! It worked. But tellme something: why '~/.bashrc' doesn't work, but '. ~/.bashrc' works? What's the meaning of the '.' before the expression? Thank you again.

Comment: @Gabriel: The dot means to source the file which runs the commands in the file in the current environment and allows variables, aliases and `cd` to remain in affect after the file exits. If you *run* it instead, changes to the environment only affect its environment rather than the parent's.

Comment: @Gabriel: If this was helpful, I would appreciate if you would upvote / accept the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `.` command is equivalent to the `source` command.  In scripts and examples, I always use `source` since its not as confusing as seeing a lone period and wondering what the heck it means.  But both do the same thing, tell the shell to execute commands stored in a shell script file in the running shell.